Systemd fails to restart a Python script with exit(0)
I have a working python script and systemd service script. But somehow it is not working the way I wanted it. The python script prints time every 5s but stops with exit(0) at first second of a minute. This is fine. The systemd seems to be working fine for the first time. Once the python script stops, it fails to restart.
My python script:
test_python_script_auto_run_linux_raspberrypi.py
from datetime import datetime
import schedule

def print_time_now():
    time_now = datetime.now()
    print("%s : This is the time now"%(time_now))

def stop_the_script():
    time_now = datetime.now()
    print("%s : Stopping the script ..."%(time_now))
    # Clean exit with no errors
    exit(0)

schedule.every(5).seconds.do(print_time_now)
schedule.every().minute.at(":01").do(stop_the_script)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()

sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/testpythonpcriptautorunmm.service
[Unit]
Description=Testing my python script for auto restart
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=60
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Documents/RaspberryPi_projects/ExamplEScripts_Practice_MM_20221209/test_python_script_auto_run_linux_raspberrypi.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Terminal commands:
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl status testpythonpcriptautorunmm.service
● testpythonpcriptautorunmm.service - Testing my python script for auto restart
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/testpythonpcriptautorunmm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2024-06-19 12:38:01 EDT; 40s ago
  Process: 816 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Documents/RaspberryPi_projects/ExamplEScripts_Practice_MM_20221209/test_python_script_auto_run_linux_raspberrypi.py (code=exited, status=0/SU
 Main PID: 816 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 19 12:37:12 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Testing my python script for auto restart.
Jun 19 12:38:01 raspberrypi python3[816]: 2024-06-19 12:37:17.883550 : This is the time now
Jun 19 12:38:01 raspberrypi python3[816]: 2024-06-19 12:37:57.454879 : This is the time now
Jun 19 12:38:01 raspberrypi python3[816]: 2024-06-19 12:38:01.000049 : Stopping the script ...
Jun 19 12:38:01 raspberrypi systemd[1]: testpythonpcriptautorunmm.service: Succeeded.
lines 1-11/11 (END)

When I run the python script on same raspberry pi using Thonny IDE:

What could be the problem? why the systemd service fails to restart the script after successful firs run?
Edit:
Updated systemd service:
[Unit]
Description=Testing my python script for auto restart
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always #on-failure#always
RestartSec=10
WatchdogSec=60
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Documents/RaspberryPi_projects/ExamplEScripts_Practice_MM_20221209/test_python_script_auto_run_linux_raspberrypi.py
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Terminal response:
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/testpythonpcriptautorunmm.service
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl status testpythonpcriptautorunmm.service
● testpythonpcriptautorunmm.service - Testing my python script for auto restart
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/testpythonpcriptautorunmm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2024-06-19 13:07:22 EDT; 4min 6s ago
  Process: 1621 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Documents/RaspberryPi_projects/ExamplEScripts_Practice_MM_20221209/test_python_script_auto_run_linux_raspberrypi.py (code=exited, status=0/S
 Main PID: 1621 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 19 13:07:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Testing my python script for auto restart.
Jun 19 13:08:01 raspberrypi python3[1621]: 2024-06-19 13:07:27.438964 : This is the time now
Jun 19 13:08:01 raspberrypi python3[1621]: 2024-06-19 13:07:32.439073 : This is the time now
Jun 19 13:08:01 raspberrypi python3[1621]: 2024-06-19 13:07:37.439153 : This is the time now
Jun 19 13:08:01 raspberrypi python3[1621]: 2024-06-19 13:07:42.439228 : This is the time now
Jun 19 13:08:01 raspberrypi python3[1621]: 2024-06-19 13:07:47.439308 : This is the time now
Jun 19 13:08:01 raspberrypi python3[1621]: 2024-06-19 13:07:52.439386 : This is the time now
Jun 19 13:08:01 raspberrypi python3[1621]: 2024-06-19 13:07:57.439471 : This is the time now
Jun 19 13:08:01 raspberrypi python3[1621]: 2024-06-19 13:08:01.000031 : Stopping the script ...

pi@raspberrypi:~ $

As per this new update, the script seems to be active after 4 minutes of operation but failed to run the script. Don't know why?

The output you've shared from systemctl status shows 40s ago, but you have RestartSec=60 set in your unit definition, so the service would wait for that amount of time before attempting a restart. Does the service restart properly if you wait for at least 60 seconds?

@Haxiel I appreciate your comment. Please find the edited question above. This time I see the script remain active after first run but fails to run the script and produce more output.

Now it is working fine. I am seeing output. exit(1) did the trick and it worked out.

I am providing the solution that worked out for me:
My python script:
test_python_script_auto_run_linux_raspberrypi.py
from datetime import datetime
import schedule
import time

def print_time_now():
    time_now = datetime.now()
    print("%s : This is the time now"%(time_now))

def stop_the_script():
    time_now = datetime.now()
    print("%s : Stopping the script ..."%(time_now))
    # Exit with errors
    exit(1)

schedule.every(5).seconds.do(print_time_now)
schedule.every().minute.at(":01").do(stop_the_script)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    # avoid high CPU usage with rapid exits
    time.sleep(1)

systemd service script:
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/testpythonpcriptautorunmm.service
[Unit]
Description=Testing my python script for auto restart
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
#on-failure#always
RestartSec=10
#WatchdogSec=60
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Documents/RaspberryPi_projects/ExamplEScripts_Practice_MM_20221209/test_python_script_auto_run_linux_raspberrypi.py
#RemainAfterExit=yes
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

On terminal:
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl enable testpythonpcriptautorunmm.service
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl start testpythonpcriptautorunmm.service
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl status testpythonpcriptautorunmm.service
● testpythonpcriptautorunmm.service - Testing my python script for auto restart
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/testpythonpcriptautorunmm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-06-19 18:00:12 EDT; 9s ago
 Main PID: 1572 (python3)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/testpythonpcriptautorunmm.service
           └─1572 /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Documents/RaspberryPi_projects/ExamplEScripts_Practice_MM_20221209/test_python_script_auto_run_linux_raspberrypi.py

Jun 19 18:00:12 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Testing my python script for auto restart.
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo journalctl -u testpythonpcriptautorunmm.service -f
-- Logs begin at Wed 2024-06-19 17:31:33 EDT. --
Jun 19 18:00:01 raspberrypi python3[1545]: 2024-06-19 17:59:46.833353 : This is the time now
Jun 19 18:00:01 raspberrypi python3[1545]: 2024-06-19 17:59:51.839333 : This is the time now
Jun 19 18:00:01 raspberrypi python3[1545]: 2024-06-19 17:59:56.845304 : This is the time now
Jun 19 18:00:01 raspberrypi python3[1545]: 2024-06-19 18:00:01.851323 : Stopping the script ...
Jun 19 18:00:01 raspberrypi systemd[1]: testpythonpcriptautorunmm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 19 18:00:01 raspberrypi systemd[1]: testpythonpcriptautorunmm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 19 18:00:12 raspberrypi systemd[1]: testpythonpcriptautorunmm.service: Service RestartSec=10s expired, scheduling restart.
Jun 19 18:00:12 raspberrypi systemd[1]: testpythonpcriptautorunmm.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 29.
Jun 19 18:00:12 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Testing my python script for auto restart.
Jun 19 18:00:12 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Testing my python script for auto restart.
Jun 19 18:01:01 raspberrypi python3[1572]: 2024-06-19 18:00:17.307845 : This is the time now
Jun 19 18:01:01 raspberrypi python3[1572]: 2024-06-19 18:00:22.314003 : This is the time now
Jun 19 18:01:01 raspberrypi python3[1572]: 2024-06-19 18:00:27.320065 : This is the time now
Jun 19 18:01:01 raspberrypi python3[1572]: 2024-06-19 18:00:32.325366 : This is the time now
Jun 19 18:01:01 raspberrypi python3[1572]: 2024-06-19 18:00:37.331469 : This is the time now
Jun 19 18:01:01 raspberrypi python3[1572]: 2024-06-19 18:00:42.337580 : This is the time now
Jun 19 18:01:01 raspberrypi python3[1572]: 2024-06-19 18:00:47.343666 : This is the time now
Jun 19 18:01:01 raspberrypi python3[1572]: 2024-06-19 18:00:52.349777 : This is the time now
Jun 19 18:01:01 raspberrypi python3[1572]: 2024-06-19 18:00:57.355768 : This is the time now
Jun 19 18:01:01 raspberrypi python3[1572]: 2024-06-19 18:01:01.360649 : Stopping the script ...
Jun 19 18:01:01 raspberrypi systemd[1]: testpythonpcriptautorunmm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 19 18:01:01 raspberrypi systemd[1]: testpythonpcriptautorunmm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 19 18:01:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: testpythonpcriptautorunmm.service: Service RestartSec=10s expired, scheduling restart.
Jun 19 18:01:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: testpythonpcriptautorunmm.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 30.
Jun 19 18:01:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Testing my python script for auto restart.
Jun 19 18:01:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Testing my python script for auto restart.
^C
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ 

It has been up and running for past 4 hours with in between reboot as well:

